# Firefox no longer prompting to remember password after having cleared them

Tags: firefox, passwords, plugins, password-management

I had changed my password for sites I visited (possibly I didn't click the "update" button the next time I logged on) and had to remove all passwords in the security tab. Now Firefox never asks me to remember passwords. I used this feature frequently.

Is there a way I can have Firefox remember my passwords and username again? If not is there a plugin I can use?

Comment: If you really removed your passwords from firefox storage and you do not have those sites stored as exceptions for storing passwd then there should not be a reason it would not ask you to save password. I would just double check.

Comment: Probably when you cleared the passwords you also cleared the "Remember passwords for sites" checkmark (or it may have been reset by the clear operation).

Comment: @DanielRHicks now how did that happen? Put that as an answer and get a checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably when you cleared the passwords you also cleared the "Remember passwords for sites" checkmark (or it may have been reset by the clear operation).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox to store passwords, I hope you are utilizing a [master password](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-master-password-protect-stored-logins).

I sincerely recommend [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) for password storage. It will, in fact, pull everything from your firefox password manager and then *replace* the firefox password manager. Same for any other browsers you have, as well as additional items. It is also accessible on the web if you aren't at home and can sync across browsers. Not to mention it will **generate** secure passwords for you, not reveal them and then store them.

Comment: The master password only appears to be necessary if the computer and account is shared. I already use Keepass.

Comment: Only necessary for a shared computer? Take a look at [this thread's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310459/how-does-firefoxs-software-security-device-protect-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help,

[Usernames and passwords are not saved](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/usernames-and-passwords-are-not-saved)

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered useful on this site. Please include the relevant part of the article (a couple of sentences would be sufficient) in your answer.